# ggplot: missing error bars and grouping lines in 3 way interaction plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the information contained in one dataframe X. However, I am not managing to include the error bars, nor the connection lines between the same coloured dots.
For now, the code to obtain the plot attached is as follows:

```
 ggplot(dataframeX, aes(x= points, y=emmean, colour= Gamers)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=emmean-SE, ymax=emmean+SE)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Team) +
  theme_light()
```

It did not working adding:

```
geom_line(aes(color=Gamers))+
geom_point(aes(ymin=emmean-SE, ymax=emmean+SE), lwd = 2.5)
```

Any idea on how should I proceed?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the desired result is. It looks to me like there are error bars. If you want to connect the dots be sure to use the proper `group=` aesthetic `geom_line(aes(color=Opponent, group=Opponent))`

Comment: You are right, there are error bars, but the limits are not marked with the usual perpendicular little line. Do you know how can I add it?

Comment: Did you just want `geom_errorbar` rather than `geom_pointrange`?

Comment: ah ok!! i needed both of them. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

As @MrFlick showed, the `group` aesthetic is important to set. You can also just use `geom_point` rather than including both `geom_errorbar` and `geom_pointrange`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(dataframeX, aes(x = Valence, y = emmean, colour = Opponent)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Valence, y = emmean), lwd = 2.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = emmean - SE, ymax = emmean + SE)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Opponent, group = Opponent)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Drug) +
  theme_light()
```

**Output**

[image]